# Appcelerator Titanum Delete File in tmpdirectory

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using Appcelerator Titanium 3.0.2 to allows user to watch/download videos&audios. Here is part of code to get the file object and play the audio.

```javascript
var filename = self.url.substring(self.url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory,filename);
if(!file.exists())
    self._download(self.url, filename, Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, function(){
      setAudUrl(file.nativePath);
      timeBar.max = audPlayer.duration*1000;
      prgHandle = setInterval(updateProgressBar,10000);
      audPlayer.play();
      audCtrlBar.show();
      loading.hide();
    },
    function(_progress,_position){
      httpClient=_position;
      loading.show();
    },
    function(){
      noLabel.show();
      loading.hide();
    });
else {
    setAudUrl(file.nativePath);
    timeBar.max = audPlayer.duration*1000;
    prgHandle = setInterval(updateProgressBar,10000);
    audPlayer.play();
    audCtrlBar.show();
}
```

This code is working, but my question is how to remove the file when the user exist the app. Since Apple required that file in /tmp directory will be removed after user exist the app. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Titanium's application events [pause](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-pause) and [paused](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-paused). They are called when the app becomes inactive but this only works on iOS.

```javascript
Titanium.App.addEventListener('pause' /* or paused, see docs */, function() {
  var dir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, 'tmpDownloads'); // ensure that you use the same folder for storing the downloaded files. A separate folder is easier to remove.
  if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
    dir.deleteDirectory(true); // true removes recursively the directory and its contents
  }
});
```

You need to create the directory again when `resume`-ing the app.

Comment: Yes. I found out this is what I have to do, but how do you loop through the tmpDirectory and deleted every single file? I have been google on the net and not able to find some sample code to use.

Comment: Wow, mr.VVoo you rock. You are actually more helpful then the Titanium Tech Support, consider we paid heavily for their support plan. I think I can do the resuming in this way                  var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'mysubdir');
dir.createDirectory();

Comment: Here is what I intend to put.  <br/> Titanium.App.addEventListener('resume',function(e)
{
 var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.tmpDirectory,'tmpDownloads');
 dir.createDirectory(); 
});